# How can I see which EC2 instances are associated with my Elastic Beanstalk application?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How can I see which EC2 instances are associated with my Elastic Beanstalk application? I can see all of my instances running in EC2 but can't tell which ones go with which Beanstalk application/environment. The Beanstalk console doesn't seem to provide this information, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented within [Listing and Connecting to Server Instances](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.ec2connect.html):

> You can view a list of Amazon EC2 instances running your AWS Elastic
>   Beanstalk application environment through the AWS Management Console.

Well, yes, but it's indeed not exactly obvious and should be easier ;) - in a nutshell, you'll need to explore the [Elastic Load Balancer](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) associated with your respective [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) environment, the screenshots in the linked article properly illustrate this at least.

Comment: It would be nice if you could set up EB to automatically tag instances when they are created by the autoscaling mechanism.

Comment: @KenLiu: Indeed, that would simplify this task a lot - tags are the most versatile and useful classification concept in cloud contexts and should be available for each and any available resource accordingly.